# Not able to upload file in symfony api-platform

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I have api resource class Email and one custom end point . I want to send a attachment via mail. I have declare as following.

```
public ?UploadedFile $attachment;
```

In my controller

```
 public function __invoke(Email $data): JsonResponse
```

I am not able to get file from $data.

Comment: How do you do it currently? How does the request look like? How do you read the data from the request?

Answer (score -2):

I recommend reading the docs. They explain how to create a route for file upload in depth: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/file-upload/#handling-file-upload

All examples are not my own they come from the linked docs!

1. Install a great bundle which will handle the uploading for you. `composer require vich/uploader-bundle`
2. configure the bundle for file destination, uri and so on

```
# api/config/packages/vich_uploader.yaml
vich_uploader:
   db_driver: orm

   mappings:
       media_object:
           uri_prefix: /media
           upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/media'
           # Will rename uploaded files using a uniqueid as a prefix.
           namer: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\OrignameNamer
```

3. Create an API resource for your file Entity. For more info check the docs of the uploader bundle: https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle

```
<?php
// api/src/Entity/MediaObject.php
namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Controller\CreateMediaObjectAction;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
#[ApiResource(
    iri: 'http://schema.org/MediaObject',
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['media_object:read']],
    itemOperations: ['get'],
    collectionOperations: [
        'get',
        'post' => [
            'controller' => CreateMediaObjectAction::class,
            'deserialize' => false,
            'validation_groups' => ['Default', 'media_object_create'],
            'openapi_context' => [
                'requestBody' => [
                    'content' => [
                        'multipart/form-data' => [
                            'schema' => [
                                'type' => 'object',
                                'properties' => [
                                    'file' => [
                                        'type' => 'string',
                                        'format' => 'binary',
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]
)]
class MediaObject
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ApiProperty(iri: 'http://schema.org/contentUrl')]
    #[Groups(['media_object:read'])]
    public ?string $contentUrl = null;

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="media_object", fileNameProperty="filePath")
     */
    #[Assert\NotNull(groups: ['media_object_create'])]
    public ?File $file = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(nullable=true)
     */
    public ?string $filePath = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

4. create a custom controller which will handle your custom POST action you just configured.

```
<?php
// api/src/Controller/CreateMediaObjectAction.php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\MediaObject;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Attribute\AsController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException;

#[AsController]
final class CreateMediaObjectAction extends AbstractController
{
    public function __invoke(Request $request): MediaObject
    {
        $uploadedFile = $request->files->get('file');
        if (!$uploadedFile) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException('"file" is required');
        }

        $mediaObject = new MediaObject();
        $mediaObject->file = $uploadedFile;

        return $mediaObject;
    }
}
```

If you want to upload your file to S3 or something you can use a filesystemabstraction like flysystem: https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/docs/storage/flysystem.md

Comment: Please do not post answers that solely point to other websites. Either edit it to contain all details, or remove it